# How to ignore errors during gulp and build files in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am facing issue in angularjs + gulp.

When i run gulp command, it gives me errors in my many .js files.

and my changes are not reflected which i have made in .js file.

Now i want to ignore those error and build .js compress file which gulp is doing.

I tried gulp --build force command also but it not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import gulp-plumber plugin 
ref-url : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber

Comment: Thanks,@MatthewShin , can you please reply me on below comment.

Answer (score -1):

This command helped me to get out of this issue:

```
gulp --local
```